Как осуществить поиск по InlineKeyboardButton в Телеграмм боте на Telebot?
Сделал телеграм бота в формате - кнопка вопроса и по нажатию полчаем сообщение с ответом. Кнопок вопроса стало очень много. Как сделать поиск по конкретной кнопке вопроса?
# 3.1.1 Платежные системы - NRI - кнопки вопроса
three1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
three1.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Замена NRI', callback_data='nri.13'))
three1.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Настройка NRI', callback_data='nri.12'))
three1.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Cashless NRI', callback_data='nri.11'))
three1.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Прошивка аудита NRI + установка даты и времени', callback_data='nri.14'))

